How can I find all the entries in one Excel file, that contain values from another Excel file?
I have two excel files with over 1000 rows. Both have a key column with an alphanumeric value. I want to find all the rows in Excel A, that contain the key of excel B, but it has to be between the 4th and 9th character.
Excel A Key examples:



Excel A




ABC1234567890ABC


789ABC1234560ABC


7890ABC123456ABC


4567890ABC123ABC



Excel B Key example:



Excel B




ABC123


7890AB



In these examples I only want to match the values 2 and 4 in Excel A, because they contain the examples from excel B between the 4th and 9th character.
Is this possible in Excel or will I need another tool to do this? Can somebody suggest me a way to solve my problem?
I tried to find a solution on google, but the problem I have seems to be too specific.

Try XLOOKUP() with MID().
=XLOOKUP(C2:C3,MID(A1:A5000,4,6),A1:A5000)




=FILTER(A1:A1000, ISNUMBER(MATCH(MID(A1:A1000, 4, 6), B1:B1000, 0)), "No Match")

Or if you like complicating things for no reason:
=LET(
    matches, FILTER(A1:A1000, BYROW(A1:A1000, LAMBDA(row, SUM(IFERROR(SEARCH(MID(row, 4, 6), B1:B1000), 0)) > 0)), "No Match"),
    FILTER(matches, matches > 0)
)

